# threads are blocked at the time of loading class via ClassUtils.java

Tags: java, classloader, apache-kafka, spring-mongo

My application listen on `kafka` topic and dump data into `cassandra`. Threads loads some information from `mongo` too. Lag in `kafka` topic getting increased. I have seen that mostly threads are blocked while loading some class. I am attaching my `thread_dump` below.

```
 "KafkaConsumer-49" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1178fdd000 nid=0x78e0 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f1155fb5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c0655b58> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.SimpleTypeInformationMapper.resolveTypeFrom(SimpleTypeInformationMapper.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1840)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1536)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.mao.TimeMachineMao.getVendorProductsForUploadId(TimeMachineMao.java:32)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.service.TimeMachineService.getVendorProductsForUploadIdAndSupc(TimeMachineService.java:35)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.event.SupcUploadIdStateUpdateEventHandler.handleEvent(SupcUploadIdStateUpdateEventHandler.java:40)



KafkaConsumer-48" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1178fdb000 nid=0x78df waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f11560b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c0655b58> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.SimpleTypeInformationMapper.resolveTypeFrom(SimpleTypeInformationMapper.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1840)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1536)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.mao.TimeMachineMao.getVendorProductsForUploadId(TimeMachineMao.java:32)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.service.TimeMachineService.getVendorProductsForUploadIdAndSupc(TimeMachineService.java:35)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.event.SupcUploadIdStateUpdateEventHandler.handleEvent(SupcUploadIdStateUpdateEventHandler.java:40)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.TimeMachine.onEvent(TimeMachine.java:109)
```

"KafkaConsumer-47" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1178fd9800 nid=0x78de waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f11561b7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c0655b58> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.SimpleTypeInformationMapper.resolveTypeFrom(SimpleTypeInformationMapper.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1840)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1536)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)

```
"KafkaConsumer-46" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1178fd8000 nid=0x78dd waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f11562b8000]
```

java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:403)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c0655b58> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.SimpleTypeInformationMapper.resolveTypeFrom(SimpleTypeInformationMapper.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(DefaultTypeMapper.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1840)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1536)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1322)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:495)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:486)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.mao.TimeMachineMao.getVendorProductsForUploadId(TimeMachineMao.java:32)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.service.TimeMachineService.getVendorProductsForUploadIdAndSupc(TimeMachineService.java:35)
        at com.snapdeal.coms.timemachine.event.SupcUploadIdStateUpdateEventHandler.handleEvent(SupcUploadIdStateUpdateEventHandler.java:40)

I am not sure why all the threads are blocked. I thought class get loaded only one time and later no need to take any lock .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `ConsumerOffsetChecker` to see if your consumers are still alive ? you can try the following command from inside your `$KAFKA_ROOT_DIR/` folder

```
  bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --group consumer-group1 --zkconnect zkhost:zkport --topic topic1
```

Here's few note taken from their [FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Myconsumerseemstohavestopped%2Cwhy%3F) page

> *If consumer offset is not moving after some time, then consumer is likely to have stopped. If consumer offset is moving, but consumer lag (difference between the end of the log and the consumer offset) is increasing, the consumer is slower than the producer. If the consumer is slow, the typical solution is to increase the degree of parallelism in the consumer. This may require increasing the number of partitions of a topic.*

the above faq pages also explains possible reasons behind your consumer getting blocked, might worth take a look at it.

Comment: i have already checked that. consumer offset is moving but lag is getting increased. i have created 100 patition on my topic and currently running 50 consumer threads. while analyzing thread dump, i saw that mostly threads are in blocked state. have attached thread dump already

Comment: `If consumer offset is moving, but consumer lag (difference between the end of the log and the consumer offset) is increasing, the consumer is slower than the producer` -- from the FAQ

Comment: that i could figured out that's why i have increased the consumer thread count. but mostly threads are in blocked state while retrieving data from mongo at class loader. i don't get why same class is getting loaded again.

Comment: does this mean your kafka is working fine? sorry m kind of confused as how exactly these two processes are related, consuming from the queue and loading from mongo. are these two separate one running in parallel?

Comment: actually my consumer threads consuming from kakfa and saving those events in cassandra but before saving it cassandra some additional information is being received from mongo too.

Comment: i have already created the 100 partition on kafka topic to increase the parallelism and created 50 consumer threads so consumer threads shouldn't be blocked on kafka stream while iterating.
is there any way i  can find out the fetcher thread rate on kakfa

Comment: so what is happening before loading data from mongo ? are you able to consume from the queue properly?if so then this is not supposed to be something related to the Kafka i guess

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the fetching data from mongo. there was huge data and pagination was not implemented and there was no socket timeout on the particular request hence threads were getting blocked.